# How to read JSON elements from Jenkinsfile for multibranch pipeline

Tags: json, jenkins, webhooks, jenkins-declarative-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I am looking for the method of pulling JSON elements from the webhook request in a jenkins **multibranch** pipeline build, which is orchestrated by a Jenkinsfile using **declarative** pipeline syntax.   (The *regular* Jenkins pipeline job has a "Generic Webhook trigger" section where you use JSONPATH to map incoming JSON elements into variables, but the multibranch pipeline seems not to have this.)

I am triggering (successfully) a pull-request build from Azure DevOps, and I need the pull request # from the JSON so I can signal back to Azure whether the build was successful or not.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: which kind of source code control  ? github, gitlab or bitbucket ?

Comment: actually Azure DevOps (git), but that shouldn't matter.  I have the PR builds working.  What is missing is to be able to pull the PR# out of the JSON request that my build server is receiving. Thks.

Comment: any solution for that?